# Font size in App change dynamically after user selects sizeof their choosing (Xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have an app settings portion in my app where the user can choose the font size of the app text size.

I thought I could use Properties.ContainsKey() in order to save the font size the user chose. Although this change is persistent upon the app close and restart, I would like these changes to happen instantly. For example, the user changes the font size mid app run, then when they click to go to a different tab or page the font size changes.

As of now I have saved the property in the App page and binder all the fonts I want to change in my app to the App property. The changes are persistent when I close and open my app but like I said when I change the font size I can roam throughout my app and the font remains the same. The only think that changes instantly is the labels I bonded with the slider where the user increases or decreases the font size.

**App.xaml.cs  public int H1Font**

```
     private const string HeaderFont = "TitleFont";
            private const string BodyFont = "BodyFont";
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Properties.ContainsKey(HeaderFont))
                    {
                        var value = Properties[HeaderFont].ToString();
                        return Int32.Parse(value);
                    }
                        
                    return 18;
                }
                set
                {
                    Properties[HeaderFont] = value;
                }
            }
            //Font for smaller labels
            public int H2Font
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Properties.ContainsKey(BodyFont))
                    {
                        var value = Properties[BodyFont].ToString();
                        return Int32.Parse(value);
    
                    }
                        
                    return 15;
                }
                set
                {
                    Properties[BodyFont] = value;
                }
            }
```

**Page1.xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemList"
                        ItemSelected="OpenCategorySelect"
                        HasUnevenRows="true"
                      >
               
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="theStacklayout" 
                                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="ItemImage" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    Source="{Binding ItemID, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                            <Label x:Name="ItemName" Text="{Binding sDescription}"  
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    FontSize="{Binding H1Font}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

**AppPrefernacePage.xaml.cs**

```
    public AppPrefernacePage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = Application.Current;
            }
    
            void FontSlider_ValueChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.ValueChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                var app = Application.Current as App;
             ...
             ...
             ...
    
                app.H1Font = h1Font;
                app.H2Font = newFont;   
            }
    
            protected override async void OnDisappearing()
            {
                base.OnDisappearing();
                await Application.Current.SavePropertiesAsync();
            }
    }
```

**AppPrefernacePage.xaml**

```
    <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="15,10,15,10">
           <Grid>
       ...
       ... 
          <Label Text="Gala Apple" Grid.Row="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference FontSlider},
                                                      Path=Value,
                                                      StringFormat='{0:N0}'}"/>
                                    <Label Text="This type of Apple is very popular."
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                           FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference fontSlider},
                                                      Path=Value,
                                                      StringFormat='{0:N0}'}"/>
    
                                    <local:StepSlider x:Name="fontSlider"
                                                      Minimum ="15"
                                                      Maximum="30"
                                                      Steps="3"
                                                      Value="{Binding H2Font}"
                                                      Grid.Row="2"
                                                      Margin="15,0,15,0"
                                                      ValueChanged="fontSlider_ValueChanged"
                                                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                      />
    
                                    <Label Text="A"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Start"
    
                                           Grid.Row="3"
                                            Margin="15,0,0,0"
                                           Grid.Column="0"
                                           />
                                    <Label Text="A"
                                           HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                           FontSize="26"
                                           Grid.Row="3"
                                           Margin="0,0,15,0"
                                           Grid.Column="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Label Text="Adjust General Settings"
                                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                                   FontSize="17"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center"
                                   Margin="15,0,5,5"
                                   Padding="5"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <Image Source="" />
                                <Label Text="Adjust General Settings"
                                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        FontSize="{Binding Source={x:Reference fontSlider},
                                                      Path=Value,
                                                      StringFormat='{0:N0}'}"
                                        HeightRequest="55"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
```

I am Binding the slider value with the font preference value as well.  As shown in

Comment: Hi, you could add `INotifyPropertyChanged` for binded property, then the value will update on runtime.

Comment: Hi Junior yes I thought about that, but what if I added this property in the App class? How can I add INotifyPropertyChanged there? Can I just make a separate class for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of Junior Jiang. I had used INotifyPropertyChanged before but had never thought of using it here. That fixed half of the problem. The other half was getting the font inside my Listview to change, because I was binding a list to the itemSource already so although I thought my changes were not being implemented, they were.
I ended up doing the following to get the solution.

```
            private const string BodyFont = "BodyFont";
            {
                get
                {
                    if (Properties.ContainsKey(HeaderFont))
                    {
                        var value = Properties[HeaderFont].ToString();
                        return Int32.Parse(value);
                    }
                        
                return 18;
            }
            set
            {
                Properties[HeaderFont] = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameOf(H1Font));

            }
        }
        //Font for smaller labels
        public int H2Font
        {
            get
            {
                if (Properties.ContainsKey(BodyFont))
                {
                    var value = Properties[BodyFont].ToString();
                    return Int32.Parse(value);

                }
                    
                return 15;
            }
            set
            {
                Properties[BodyFont] = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameOf(H2Font));

            }
        }---------------------------------------------- **Page1**---------------------
<ListView x:Name="ItemList"
                        ItemSelected="OpenCategorySelect"
                        HasUnevenRows="true">
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout x:Name="theStacklayout" 
                                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="ItemImage" 
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    Source="{Binding ItemID, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"/>
                            <Label x:Name="ItemName" Text="{Binding sDescription}"  
                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.H1Font, Source={x:Reference Name=NameOfThisPage}}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    **Page1.xaml.cs**
    BindingContext = Application.Current;
```

Comment: Hey, Junior Jiang this is somewhat related but, everything is working fine however could this same approach work for resizing my list view rows? They resize on onApearing with HasUnevenRows=true but not instantly like when using OnProprtyChanged(). I can ask a new question if needed but I thought the approach might be the same.

Comment: Hi, you could create a new question in SO, then can share the link here.

Comment: hi yes I just posted it here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838416/auto-size-listview-height-when-list-view-item-gets-modified-xamarin