# Auto size ListView height when ListView item gets modified

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been having some issues resizing my list view row to match the text inside of it.  Also I have read a lot of documentation and everything seems to point toward using `HasUnevenRows`, which I am using  but isn't quite what I need.

I have a `ListView` which I allow the user to modify contents of this row using `Rg.Popups` and context actions. Essentially the user swipes and clicks Edit and they get pushed to a popup where they can edit the list view item.

When the note gets updated it also gets updated on my `ListView` however if the note is more than 1 line the row will not resize. I have to leave the page and come back to it for the row to resize to fit the entire note.

Below is my code.

```
  <ListView  x:Name="MyItemList"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       ItemSelected="OpenRecipeDetails"
                       IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                       HasUnevenRows="true">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell x:Name="myViewcell">
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="MenuItem_Clicked" Text="Edit Note" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                                            Grid.Row="0"
                                            Grid.Column="0"
                                            FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.H1Font, Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}"
                                            Padding="5"
                                            
                                            LineBreakMode="WordWrap">
                                    </Label>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding sNote}"
                                           Grid.Row="1"
                                           Grid.Column="0"  
                                           FontSize="{Binding BindingContext.H2Font, Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}"
                                          >
                                    </Label>
                                </Grid>
                               <!-- -->
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
             </ListView>
```

CodeBehind

```
//for editing the note
 async void MenuItem_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
            updatedItem = menuItem.CommandParameter as MyItemBooklet;
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new EditNotesPopupPage(updatedItem));
        }
```

EditNotesPopupPage

```
 public EditNotesPopupPage( MyItemBooklet item)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _item = item;
        }
...
  async void Cancel_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        }

       async void Ok_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
           ...
           ...

            await db.UpdateNote(text, _item.iRecipeLinkID);
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Prayag's answer is helpful, you could have a try to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try force update size of ViewCell below is the link with good sample that will guide you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-listview-dynamicunevenlistcells/

Comment: Hi Prayag, so I am having trouble implementing this. I think writing a custom ViewCell and then implementing the ForceUpdateSize() within the Height property might be more beneficial. This is because I perform the updated to the data on a different page and I just use PopAsync to come back to the page with the ListView. so the data changes but no the height. Not sure if that was clear from my code snippet.

Comment: That doesn't matter your menu click is inside the ViewCell u may send Complete ViewCell as commandparameter or any other way that seems convenient to u(it is possible in more than one way) and then perform forceupdatesize.

Comment: I see, okay and what is this is only happening in my IOS not in android?

Comment: @uzzum07 Hi, if so you could share the sample project link here, I will check that.